# Javascript 'this'

Tags: javascript

Can you explain me why does the second call of `fn` gives an error? The code is below.

```
function Test(n) {
  this.test = n;

  var bob = function (n) {
      this.test = n;
  };

  this.fn = function (n) {
    bob(n);
    console.log(this.test);
  };
}

var test = new Test(5);

test.fn(1); // returns 5
test.fn(2); // returns TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
```

Here's a JSfiddle that reproduces the error http://jsfiddle.net/KjkQ2/

Comment: They both print `5` for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jEgLM/

Comment: P.S. You probably want `bob.call(this, n)`.

Comment: You should read about the 'this' keyword in Javascript, it points to the closes function scope if can find, you can fix this by doing "var self = this;" in the "outter" function and then using "self" instead of "this" in the inner functions.

Comment: @RocketHazmat The reason it doesn't break in jsfiddle is that everything is wrapped in a function, so `var test = new Test(5)`  creates a local variable, not a global that conflicts with `this.test = n`

Comment: @gosukiwi Your statement "points to the closest function scope it can find" is completely wrong and misleading. `this` has nothing to do with function scope. `this` is dynamic and changes depending on how the function was called. You should read up on `this` or at least express yourself better

Comment: @JuanMendes Well, you can write a complete articule about the this keyword, or just give him a tip about his problem. "Javascript the good parts" is a good read about "this"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `bob` function is called from the global scope. Thefore, `this.test` is pointing at a global variable named `test` which is overwriting the variable you created. If you run `console.log(window.test)`, you'll what's happening.

For your code to behave as intended, you would need one of the following

```
function Test(n) {
  this.test = n;

  // If a function needs 'this' it should be attached to 'this'       
  this.bob = function (n) {
      this.test = n;
  };

  this.fn = function (n) {
    // and called with this.functionName
    this.bob(n);
    console.log(this.test);
  };
}
```

OR

```
function Test(n) {
  this.test = n;

  var bob = function (n) {
      this.test = n;
  };

  this.fn = function (n) {
    // Make sure you call bob with the right 'this'
    bob.call(this, n);
    console.log(this.test);
  };
}
```

OR closure based objects

```
// Just use closures instead of relying on this
function Test(n) {
  var test = n;

  var bob = function (n) {
      test = n;
  };

  this.fn = function (n) {
    bob(n);
    console.log(test);
  };
}
```

Comment: your first solution won't work. `this` still references to `window` when called like `this.bob()`;

Comment: @jAndy Not true, it was called as `test.fn()` so `test` is the context. See http://jsfiddle.net/jEgLM/1/

Answer (score 3):

When calling `bob(n)` within `.fn`, it is called within the `global context` (`window` in a browser). Now, you're setting `window.test = n;` which basically overwrites your function `test` object you created earlier.

If we you write this more explicit, it becomes more obvious:

```
// in the global scope, `test` gets written to the `global object`
// window.test = new Test(5);
var test = new Test(5);

test.fn(1); // returns 5
test.fn(2); // returns TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
```

You can "workaround" this issue by calling `bob()` with an explicit context, using `.call()` for instance:

```
this.fn = function (n) {
   bob.call(this,n);
   console.log(this.test);
};
```

---

The root of evil here is, that the value of `this` is dynamically assigned during run-time. Don't get me wrong, its actually a great feature of ECMAscript - it's just the problem for you here. When you call a function, "*just like that*", `this` will always reference the global object.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call `bob.call(this, n)`, not just `bob(n)`.

When you call `bob(n)`, the value of `this` is *not* your object, it's `window`.  Therefore, your `test` variable is replaced with `1`.

In jsFiddle, the code is wrapped in a function, so `window.test` does not exist at first.